# Which GenerationType should I use with hibernate and with already existing table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have a problem where `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` is not working properly.  I have the error saying that `kcyn.hibernate_sequence` does not exist.

I read to following topic : [hibernate could not get next sequence value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628099/hibernate-could-not-get-next-sequence-value/15286642).  It says that I should change `AUTO` by `IDENTITY`.  But then, I have an error saying that a NULL value is added into primary key.

If I am starting from an non existing table, with `AUTO` strategy, hibernate auto-magically creates `airroute` table with an `hibernate_sequence` table.

But, since I want to work with an existing database, my question would be, which `GenerationType` should I use in order to have my id automatically generated?

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.*;    
@Entity
public class Airroute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;    
    public String label;        
    public String spokenname;        
    public Boolean internal;        
    public String descr;        
    public String direction;
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
Maxsim=# \d+ "KCYN-GOLD-USMC_3_141_553".airroute
                    Table "KCYN-GOLD-USMC_3_141_553.airroute"
   Column   |      Type      | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+----------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | numeric(11,0)  | not null  | main     |              |
 label      | character(8)   |           | extended |              |
 spokenname | character(60)  |           | extended |              |
 internal   | boolean        |           | plain    |              |
 descr      | character(250) |           | extended |              |
 direction  | character(1)   |           | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "airroute_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: If you have an existing table why dont you actually POST the DDL for the table???

Comment: @BillyFrost Post updated with more information.

Answer (score 0):

As any JPA doc would tell you,

- `AUTO` means let the JPA provider do whatever it likes (so you may not get what you want)
- `SEQUENCE` will use a SEQUENCE in the RDBMS (which Postgresql supports, so an option for your case)
- `TABLE` will create a table in the DB to hold id values (also an option for your case)
- `IDENTITY` will require a column type of `SERIAL` which you haven't got on that column (**not an option**).

For `SEQUENCE` and `TABLE` the JPA provider will need to be able to create either a SEQUENCE or a TABLE respectively in that schema (and be configured to do so)