# Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() takes very long time to return

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I am using Hibernate 4.2, JPA 2.0 & Postgres 9.2

The code gets stuck at `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("peristence_unit_name");`

On further investigation I found that Hibernate makes a call to `getTypeInfo()` method of `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` class. This method tries to load metadata about every database object

```
/**
 * Perform the extraction
 *
 * @param metaData The JDBC metadata
 *
 * @return The extracted metadata
 */
public static LinkedHashSet<TypeInfo> extractTypeInfo(DatabaseMetaData metaData) {
    LinkedHashSet<TypeInfo> typeInfoSet = new LinkedHashSet<TypeInfo>();
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = metaData.getTypeInfo(); // << Gets stuck here.
        try {
             ......
```

The code for `getTypeInfo()` is part of Postgers' JDBC drivers and it is indeed the driver thats taking time to execute the method (I loaded the driver source and tried following the trail). But since this problem did not occur in Hibernate 3.3 (which I was using earlier), I think, Hibernate 3.3 was not calling this method, but Hibernate 4.2 is.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Note that the same setup with Hibernate 3.3 was working fine.

Extra Info :
What the driver is doing all this time:

It first gets the list of database objects and then loops through the resultset to get metadata of each object.

There are around 3000 objects in the DB (I have a very large data-set requiring many partition tables. Plus PostGIS has many objects of its own)

It takes about 1 second per object lookup, so it takes about 3000 seconds to finish the call.

Comment: *1s per Lookup*? That's crazy, is that postgres taking so long, ie does it show up in the slowlog?

Comment: It's a remote server plus I am not being accurate. The ping time itself is 300 ms So even if one were to manage to reduce Postgres server processing time to 0, 3000 roundtrips would take 900 seconds. This is still too slow. I think the solution lies in eliminating those 3000 calls and not in trying to make them happen faster.

Comment: Tried with 9.2 first also tried 9.1 & 9.3. Same result. Version 3.3 of Hibernate never calls that JDBC method and works well. These are JDBC4 Drivers.

Comment: Exact driver versions: `postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar`, `postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar`, `postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar` and `postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar` (For Java 7 & above)

Comment: I've got the same problem and while I can roll the version of Hibernate I'm using back to 3.6.10 for my utilities, the main program runs on an application server ... I'm facing a 22 minutes start-up (with 17000+ sequences).  I haven't (yet) found a switch for this behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same problem and for some reason it takes long time to extract JDBC metadata for hibernate.
You can just turn off using jsbc metadata for hibernate and it will become very fast. But remember that hibernate is not using jdbc metadata and will use some defaults instead.

To try this out set `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` to false.

```
 <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. But IMO, the proper solution would probably need code changes from Postgres or Hibernate developers.

Comment: more on this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075081/hibernate-slow-to-acquire-postgres-connection